# Vue: How to change tab title in Chrome

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How do I change the default "Webpack App" tab title in Vue.js?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have at least two options:

```
document.title = 'Your new name'
```

or in the `index.html`-file:

```
<head>
 <title>Your new name</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 8):

In Your public/index.html  or other HTML files used as templates by html-webpack-plugin. find title tag and change it

```
 <title>Page Title</title>
```

Or you can set the page title dynamically by getting the title from document `document.title` and change it inside your component like the code below :

```
<template>
        <div id="app"></div>
</template>
<script>
     export default {
            name: "App",
            mounted() {
                  document.title = "page title";
                      },};
                   
              </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will find  `<title>Webpack App</title>` in `index.html` in most probably `public` folder. You can change it

Answer (score 0):

We needed to fix this in the webpack config which generated the index.html every time we deployed our Storybook app.

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = async ({ config }) => {
  config.plugins.push(
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ title: 'Storybook — Company Name' }),
  )

  return config
}
```